# jquery div height run time issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Please see the below code

```
panelHeight = $('.panel:eq(' + x + ')', slider).height();
```

it returns the height correctly. If the height varies run time it is not returnts the current value.

ie By normal condition i have 2 paragraph of text inside the div. SO the height is 100px.
Under onclick,  the text will be varied from 2 paragraph to 5 paragraph. At that time the height is 500px. But it shows the height as 100px.

How to get this height.

Please refer this url http://vsoftdemos.com/coda/err.html
We used coda slider. 
Here  if you change the Teams: dropdown from 16 to 22 then 'Invite or Remove Owners' section have more data than they previously appear. At that time some of the 'Division Alignment' section content will disappear. We know this is due to height proble. But i dont know how to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

See also innerHeight() and outerHeight() when you want to include padding / borders / margins.

when rou are running this cript onchage or click or live tell me..please give detail in your problem.. detailed code also.. may be i can help u.

```
$(selector).height(function(index,oldheight))
```

Specifies a function that returns the new height of selected elements.
index - Optional. Receives the index position of the selector
oldheight - Optional. Receives the current height of the selector

Answer (score 0):

If you had passed the height inline in the beginning then this may help. Here I remove the already passed height to the div.

```
$('div').css('height', '').height();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mKJ9w/

Or in case of css issue, remove `overflow:hidden` from `.coda-slider` css class.

Comment: Please refer this url <http://vsoftdemos.com/coda/err.html> We used coda slider 
Here  if you change the Teams: dropdown from 16 to 22 then 'Invite or Remove Owners' section have more data than they previously appear. At that time some of the 'Division Alignment' section content will disappear. We know this is due to height proble. But i dont know how to fix this. Please help.

Comment: Still the problem occurs And all the hidden panel are also opened.

Comment: Do you just want the elements below 'division alignment' line to be visible?

Comment: Why do you need the height to be specified for 'coda-slide-1' div? I do not think its necessary and it will resolve your issue as well.

Comment: no i haven't set any height in coda slider. It automatically takes the height of the div to remove the unwanted spacing at the bottom.  In my criteria the height is automatically varied due to the onchange event. So it hides some of the page content. this is my problem.

Comment: The height thing is causing an issue. Either you have to remove the height attribute dynamically once the page is loaded using Javascript or you could remove overflow:hidden from 'coda-slider-1' css class as I told earlier.